# Сделать Bitmap чисто черно белым

Tags: java, kotlin, изображения

Мне надо сделать фото чисто черно белым чтоб было только два цвета 0 и 256

Пример
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
А на выходе должно быть тоже самое но только цифры чисто черные а фон чисто белый.

Кто подскажет как это реализовать пожалуйста...
Что то на подобии image segmentation///help pls...
Это нужно в android studio, код java или kotlin

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Помимо моего ответа, в инете есть другие варианты, например https://stackoverflow.com/a/14513703/312041 , https://memorynotfound.com/convert-image-black-white-java/ , https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-converting-image-grayscale-using-cvtcolor/#:~:text=Syntax%3A%20File%20input%20%3D%20new%20File,()%20in%20the%20Imgproc%20class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я нашел более лучшее решение оно касается платформы android (kotlin):

```
fun subColor(src:Bitmap): Bitmap? {
    val output = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(src, 600,200, true )
    for (x in 0 until output.width) for (y in 0 until output.height) {
        val pixel = output.getPixel(x, y)

        val r: Int = pixel shr 16 and 0xff
        val g: Int = pixel shr 8 and 0xff
        val b: Int = pixel shr 0 and 0xff
        val Y = 0.2126*r + 0.7152*g + 0.0722*b

        if (Y < 128) {
            output.setPixel(x, y, Color.BLACK)
        }else{
            output.setPixel(x, y, Color.WHITE)
        }

    }
    return output
}
```

Было -
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Стало -
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Не претендую на лучший алгоритм, но я делал когда то следующее:

1. разбить картинку на пиксели
2. для каждого пикселя определить, будет ли он белым или черным цветом в итоге
3. собрать вторую, черно-белую картинку

Я когда то давным давно баловался с этим, фрагменты кода просто для примера

```
var po = 15; // порог цвета       
var w = image.Width;
var h = image.Height;
var nrgb = new bool[w*h]; // карта для новой картинки
    
for(var i = 0; i<w; i++)
{
    for(var j=0; j<h; j++)
    {            
        var color = Color.FromArgb(rgb[i+j*w]);            
        var dr = Math.Abs(c.R-color.R);
        var dg = Math.Abs(c.G-color.G);
        var db = Math.Abs(c.B-color.B);
        if (dr < po && dg < po && db < po) // если все цвета ниже порога
        {
            nrgb[i+j*w] = false; // то белый цвет в итоговой картинке
        }
        else
        {
            nrgb[i+j*w] = true; // иначе черный 
        }                    
    }
}
```

Код выше помог мне превратить фотки во так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Зачем это мне понадобилось я писал тут https://tym32167.blogspot.com/2013/09/linqpad.html

Comment: что значит порог цвета ?именно значение 15

Comment: если картинка большого разрешения то приложение подвиснет как я понял

Comment: @Tikhon цвет же состоит из частей, например красного, зеленого и синего. Каждая составляющая цвета показана числом от 0 до 255. Я просто опытным путем нашел, что для моего конкретного случая (не факт, что у вас также), если любой цвет из RGB выше 15, то значит итог надо писать черным, иначе белым.

Comment: @Tikhon скорость будет зависеть от того, как вы это закодите на джаве (мой код на сишарпе) + что в вашем понимании "большое разрешение"